# Can ApplicationInsights telemetry help diagnose high CPU usage issues?

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, azure, iis, azure-application-insights

At work, we have an application that will periodically fall under heavy CPU usage for a lengthy period of time (> 1 hour). The application is hosted under IIS and runs alongside other applications. This application is built in .NET 4.5, using ASP.net MVC 5.

We have added Application Insights to most applications running under this server, and looking at a past event I can see the CPU spiking for a long period of time. If I compare the telemetry from other AppInsights instances, there's barely no CPU usage for the same period. From this, I can assume I have found the web app that is causing the high CPU usage.

Going forward, I'd like to identify what request(s) triggers that intensive CPU usage.
I can see the requests that were sent just before the event, but nothing runs for the duration of these spikes.

Is there anything with ApplicationInsights that can help me pinpoint which request caused the high CPU usage ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Find and diagnose performance issues with Azure Application Insights](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/learn/tutorial-performance)

Specifically, look at the "[profiler](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/profiler-overview)", which should give you some more insights into your performance.

[image: performance hot paths]

Comment: Thanks for the profiler suggestion. Unfortunately it wasn't set up properly for our past CPU spike events, but I'll make sure to set it up properly.

Comment: For people wondering, there's no built-in support for the profiler when running on premise under IIS. I found this article mentionning how to set it up : https://unhandled.wordpress.com/2018/02/01/using-azure-application-insights-with-on-premises-servers/. There's a package to install for the profiler agent that can be found here on Github : https://github.com/CawaMS/AIProfiler-Standalone